# Nestjs --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket' | property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'

Tags: nestjs

I use my app of nestjs. It throws an error of JSON.stringfy in passport,when i was using the serializeUser. And i change the user to ""
, It will throws the error of Failed to serialize user into session.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xm1H.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgrMe.png)

Comment: the issue here is that you're calling `JSON.stringify` in a object with circular references.

Comment: I know that,but I don't kown where i need to modify it.

Comment: Thanks , guys .I repair It.  It can run when I changed the request method to "Get".